# cant pass data between Django and Chartjs

Tags: python, django

I wanted to pass an array to chartjs for a chart the data is getting passed but for some strange reason the data gets changed,  the array contains days of the month [1,2,3,so on] but on chart it displays "[ 0 1 3 5 7 9 0 so on ]"

the data is good when I print it to console

```
    return render(request, 'notes/home.html',{
        'day':daysOfMonth,
    })
```

```
 <div class="mainChart">
          <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
  
          <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
          
          <script>
            const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
            const days = '{{day}}';
            
            new Chart(ctx, {
              type: 'bar',
              data: {
                labels: days,
                datasets: [{
                  // label: '# of Votes',
                  data: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,],
                  borderWidth: 10
                }]
              },
              options: {
                scales: {
                  y: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                  }
                }
              }
            });
          </script>
          
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the context data like this

```
'day':json.dumps(daysOfMonth)
```

and is the template change is to this

```
 var days = JSON.parse('{{day|safe}}');
```